# which is fastest for an oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

This

```
select * from customers where id = 1;
select * from customers where id = 2;
```

or

```
select * from customers where id in(1,2);
```

which is faster?

Comment: Try it. Look at the explain plan.

Comment: The first returns two collections each containing one row. The second returns one collection containing 2 rows. They do not give the same result so compairing them is meaningless. Need more context for a meaningfull question.

Answer (score 5):

The first one are actually two statements causing you to make two roundtrips to the database.
The second one will most likely be faster as it is just one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really what you are trying to determine? Are you asking if it is faster to make one trip returning two rows or two trips each returning one row? If that is the question, then I agree with the comments -- try it, measure it, and compare.

If you are trying to make this kind of thing efficient, then you should probably look at using bind variables instead. If your question really means what it says, then probably any answer here will do.

Answer (score 0):

Any question with "faster" is always going to be dependent on the specifics of your database. I don't really have anything to add over plhmhck and MJB about the fact that you're talking about 2 queries vs. 1 query.

But be aware the the optimizer will usually (always?) rewrite `WHERE id IN (1,2)` to `WHERE (id = 1 OR id = 2)`